# Does data-id violate separation of concerns

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

My question is simple:

Does adding the "data-" notation to your mark-up  violate MVC's separation of concerns?

Example:
`<div id="myDiv" data-id="34"></div>`

or if you're using a templating system, then
`<div id="myDiv" data-id="{{myPrimaryKey}}"></div>`

There's some debate about that amongst my co-workers.  My opinion is that it does violate SoC because you are embedding data into your HTML mark-up (AKA your view).  It seems like anything within your markup should only be concerned with the actual displaying/formatting data. But maybe I'm being too much of a purist?

Background: The project that trigged this discussion is a pure JavaScript client with RESTful web services as the back end.  Data is retrieved via AJAX calls to the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being too much of a purist. This is what the `data-` stuff was made for. Sometimes you need to annotate nodes with user data so that you can make URLs and stuff to query the server or for JavaScript's benefit.

Comment: Well, I understand what the purpose of `data-` is.  We've been trying out Backbone.js and javascriptMVC for MVC (or MVC-ish in Backbone's case) and for all intents and purposes, we can do what we need without adding the 'data-' attributes with those libraries because we'll have a model in scope that can provide the data we need, provided we structured our views well.  THe trade off is that we end up with many, very granular views.  Which may or may not be a good thing in and of itself.

Comment: Well many granular views would seem to violate the DRY principle. :)

Comment: Not really... the view is written once.  For example, if you have a list of widgets, each item in the list is its own instance of the view.  thats what i meant.  Here's a simple example: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

Comment: Having each item in a list be its own separate instance is probably not the end of the world (assuming reasonable object sizes and list member numbers, of course). So I'd say just do whatever results in the most concise and understandable code. Either way should probably work.